# outer join between tables

Tags: sql-server, join

There is a table `table1` having a column `hId`. This can contain numerical also, including also `0` and `null`. After some joining relation, each `table1.hId` have a `full name`, but only if `hId !=0 or null`

Then `table2.Hpid = table1.hId -- but only if hId is not null or != 0`

After this, `table2.exId = table3.Id` and, finally, `table3.lId = table4.Id`

What I've tried

```
SELECT
  (SELECT table4.fullName
   FROM table4
   WHERE table4.Id = table3.lId)
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.hId = table2.hpId
JOIN table3 ON table3.Id = table2.exId
```

But in this way I get only the rows where `table1.id = table2.hId`. I believe I have to use a `case` statement ( and when `table.hId = 0 or null` => then print 'error' ) , but how can I achieve this?

Comment: Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com it will be much easier to help.

Comment: there is an error in the query: what's `ed.Id` in `JOIN table3 ON ed.Id = table2.exId`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can't understand the goal but try to go with left joins:

```
SELECT ISNULL(table4.Id, 'ERROR') AS Table4Id
       , table4.fullName
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.holidayparkid2 = table2.Id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON ed.Id = table2.exId <-- what's ed.Id?
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table4.Id = table3.lId;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (table.hId = 0 OR table.hId IS NULL) THEN 'ERROR'
            ELESE table4.fullName
       END AS fullName
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.holidayparkid2 = table2.Id
JOIN table3 ON ed.Id = table2.exId
JOIN table4 ON table4.Id = table3.lId
--WHERE table1.hId!=0 AND table1.hId IS NOT NULL  --not need with case
```